# Did Emiko have a hand in the Queen's Gambit sinking?

Tags: dc, arrowverse

A recent episode of Arrow ended with a flashback- Emiko is watching the news as it reports the yacht Queen's Gambit lost in a storm; shortly afterward she is seen burning some paper blueprints of the Queen's Gambit. Is it safe to assume she somehow sabotaged the yacht?

Answer (score 1):

She didn’t have anything to do with sabotaging it. She just had proof that it was being sabotaged.

She was going to tell Robert Queen about it until he rejected her. In that moment she decided to keep it to herself and let him sail to his death.